# on Windows 10 phpMyAdmin displaying The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I already checked in `php.ini` that

```
extension=mbstring
extension=exif
extension=pdo_mysql
```

are uncommented.

The `mysqli.dll` file is at ext folder in PHP.
I restarted my server and run as administrator.
I also restarted my PC but the error is still there.
I am using PHP7.4.3 with Apache 2.4 and MySQL 8 with phpMyAdmin.

Comment: First do check what is your php version in cmd.
Then create a phpinfo file and check the version here and let me know both are same or different

Comment: yes both versions are same

Comment: okay, then do check mysqli.dll is located inside the extension folder

Comment: What about the `mysqli` extension line in `php.ini`? You don't mention it.

Comment: I uncommented mysqli from php.ini

Comment: @Rohit yes mysql.dll is at ext folder

Comment: then check the mysqli in phpinfo file. send a screenshot of mysqli from phpinfo

Comment: i just remove everthing and move to XAMPP every thing is well working

Answer (score 0):

add path in extension php.ini file.
like this ...
extension=E:\Aplikasi\XAMPP\php\php_mysqli.dll

Answer (score 0):

I had got the same issue and found out that there are 2 PHP on my machine. So, I changed listen port to another port 81 in httpd.conf.